# Why does my twitter bootstrap navbar keeps moving about?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How do i stop my twitter bootstrap navbar from moving up and down or even behind my image button when i reduce my browser size? The bootstrap CSS file is the latest one i have downloaded.

Initially my previous navbar i created myself was able to be fixed onto one position which managed to overlap my other picture.

The code below is my own navbar which i created ( NOT MY TWITTER BOOTSTRAP css code ). Bootstrap CSS code are pretty standardized and can be downloaded

```
#nav {
background: #292929;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black, #3c3c3c 1px, #292929 25px);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(black), color-stop(4%, #3c3c3c), to(#292929));
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:10%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
border: 1px yellow;
border-bottom: none;
width:100%;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is the otherwise for my twitter bootstrap.
I'm new to twitter bootstrap so i'm quite confused when i went to see their CSS. I tried changing the position to fixed but it's still the same.

***UPDATE***

I'm able to let my twitterbootstrap navbar overlap my slideshow image and imagebutton by encasing it with another

```
<div id="overalltwitternavbar">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">iPolice</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="Login.aspx">Login</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my css for the encasing div

```
#overalltwitternavbar {
position:relative;

}
```

However, I'm still unable to force the navbar to fixed into a position and just collapse the menu accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's a mistake which people tend to overlook very often

Just replace

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
```

With

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

Twitterbootstrap has multiple css ready-made for all users. Therefore, actually by changing the css class id will force the navbar to be fixed rather than static which is rather self-explanatory by the css name itself.

For those who are confused, you can always refer to this [link](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) for better explaination.

Answer (score 2):

It probably has something to do with the responsive settings.  Try placing the same code in a set of media queries, so...

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #nav {
       position:absolute;
       left:0%;
       top:10%;
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0;
       border: 1px yellow;
       border-bottom: none;
       width:100%;
       z-index:9999;
    }
}
```

Obviously I don't know at what screen size your nav bar is messing up at, so you would need to adjust the pixel width in the query.

I would also recommend applying a `z-index` to help with the overlapping issue.  Just stick it in the media query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting z-index:1000 and using a pixel value for top: instead of percent?

Changing the z-index should ensure it stays above other elements, and using a pixel value should ensure it won't move around when you adjust your browser size. You'll likely still see some problems on smaller screens, but you can more easily use media queries to correct this.

Comment: Which z-index do you mean? there are tons of z-index in the jquery and CSS file.

Comment: `background: #292929;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black, #3c3c3c 1px, #292929 25px);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(black), color-stop(4%, #3c3c3c), to(#292929));
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:50px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
border: 1px yellow;
border-bottom: none;
width:100%;
z-index: 1000;`

I meant to add z-index as a property to #nav

Comment: Please read my question carefully. The code i gave above is the very first navbar, but not my twitter bootstrap.

Comment: You should give us the code you're using.  The code that's causing the problem.

Comment: However, i did not change the twitter bootstrap codes. twitter bootstrap codes are very lengthy and it would be very tedious if i were to paste their codes. I'm also confused which code linked to my navbar.